# how to create UISlider type view automatically switching to number of pages in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uislider, uipagecontrol

[image: how to create this type of UIView in objective-c i tried to create horizontal scrolling but not same as this view.]

I have already tried with Horizontal Scroll but not like the picture uploaded. I Need to create that type of view .I have no idea kindly help thanks in advance

Comment: may be it is use full to you please check it https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @rohitSidpara thanks for suggesting but how can i put uibutton indicator as given in image ?

Comment: you can put to scroll one is for your photo and other is for your button.

Comment: @rohitSidpara i tried this way but not done same as any other way ?

Comment: you tried in iCarousel?

Comment: @rohitSidpara ya But i made with UIPageController and UIPageControl

Comment: @rohitSidpara I tried with iCarousel but images is not proper set as in picture as above in question.so any idea?

Comment: see this it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041365/how-to-use-uipagecontrol-with-icarousel

Comment: @rohitSidpara if images and labels are empty how to display "no data available" message in iCarousel.?