# Paging with iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I am using iCarousel to show images in my view. These images are coming from Web end. Now I want to implement paging in iCarousel to view 10 images per page than call web service again and get other images. How can I achieve this with iCarousel?

Comment: Hope any of these helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10041563/775896     http://snipplr.com/view/60971/

Comment: Use SDWebImage in app. it will download images in background and cached for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download 10 images before show them with iCarousel.if iCarousel moves to the last image,download 10 other images.Don't forget using HUD to keep user waiting for the download.